# Text clustering with KL divergence

Tags: text, scikit-learn, cluster-computing, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to cluster texts,for each one I have defined a language model, based on smoothed Dirichlet priors bigrams, so I would like to use k-means algorithm to do that, using KL divergence maybe as the clustering function. Is there any guidance to do that?Am I able to use one of the classic similarity measures such as cosine similarity?

Thank you in advance